# xwatermark causing issues with \includegraphics options

Tags: includegraphics, options, xwatermark

I'm currently having issues using `xwatermark` and the `clip` and `trim={}` options of `\includegraphics` for graphics that are completely unrelated to the watermark produced by `xwatermark`. Here's a MWE that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[extendedchars,encoding,filenameencoding=utf-8]{grffile}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarks,raiselinks,pageanchor,hyperindex,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

% The problem package
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\begin{document}

    CTAN lion draw­ing by Duane Bibby.

    % This works with \usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio]{ctan-lion.png}
    \end{figure}

    % This doesn't work with \usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio,clip,trim={2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm}]{ctan-lion.png}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When commenting out `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}` the following correct PDF is produced:[image: Correct PDF]

If the document is compiled with `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}` active the following LaTeX errors are reported:

```
! Paragraph ended before \Gread@parse@vp was complete.<to be read again>\par
! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 32 ended by \end{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{document}
! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.\enddocument ...cumenthook \deadcycles \z@ \@@end \end{document}
! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 32 ended by \end{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{document}
! Emergency stop.<> xwatermark-issue.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:18296 strings out of 492639284815 string characters out of 6133102404018 words of memory out of 1200000021996 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+6000007211 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819153i,6n,58p,860b,638s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've tracked the problem down to the `clip` and `trim={}` options of the second `\includegraphics` in the MWE.  If **BOTH** options are omitted the the document compiles fine when using `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}`. Does anyone have any insight as to why `xwatermark` is interfering with the options of `\includegraphics` or how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use xwatermark. It is a quite intrusive package with known interference to other packages. Your example is a proof: it redefines an internal graphics command and so breaks the normal key handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the `\includegraphics` options: `clip` **after** `trim` (with no braces).

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio,trim=2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm,clip]{example-image-a}
```

Comment: I've confirmed that your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you for the help!